# How to install vcremote on mac os 10.14?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, cross-platform

I've updated on Mac OS Mojave 10.14 and wanna install vcremote on it.
the command I run is

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote
```

taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/install-and-configure-tools-to-build-using-ios?view=vs-2017#Prerequisites

I installed Xcode, have created Apple Id and added it to the Xcode, Node and other stuff from the link above.

but after

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote
```

I receive the strange errors:

node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.31
node-pre-gyp info using node@11.6.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp verb command install []
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v67-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.1.0/node_ios_device-v1.1.0-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.1.0/node_ios_device-v1.1.0-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.1.0/node_ios_device-v1.1.0-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-ios-device@1.1.0 and node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.1.0/node_ios_device-v1.1.0-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp verb command build [ rebuild ]
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://appc-node-binaries.s3.amazonaws.com/node-ios-device/v1.1.0/node_ios_device-v1.1.0-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-ios-device@1.1.0 and node@11.6.0 (node-v67 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

so according to this log I receive 403 error from Amazon (
what I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have exactly same errors on latest version, vcremote@1.0.14 , npm@6.5.0 , node@11.6.0 .

It looks like amazon deleted latest node_ios_device-v1.1.0-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz .

But I have already solved my trouble, I found workaround.

Prerequisite

```
xcode-select --install
```

First we need to downgrade node version to 8.9.3,

use NVM to manage more than one version

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

then install an old version:

```
nvm install 8.9.3
```

use in your open terminal:

```
nvm use 8.9.3
```

or set as default:

```
nvm alias default 8.9.3
```

verify the version with:

```
node -v
v8.9.3
```

Second you need to install and rebuild from source

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm vcremote --build-from-source
```

Thats all, need to mention, this issue looks similar to [sqlite3 issue](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/758)

Comment: Did debugging work? see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920868/trying-to-debug-native-ios-app-with-vs-2019?noredirect=1#comment100554316_56920868