# Trying to debug native iOS App with VS 2019

Tags: c++, ios, visual-studio

I'm trying to use VS 2019 to install and debug a native iOS project.

I 've followed instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/install-and-configure-tools-to-build-using-ios?view=vs-2019), installed Node from [here](https://nodejs.org/fr/blog/release/v8.11.3/).

The app builds and installs to my device (note: only over USB. If trying in WiFi mode, I got an error `Failed to fetch the first device. Reason: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`).

However the application won't run.  Tried (from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55197/cross-platform-ios-app-fail-to-debug-on-device.html)):

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/db/lockdown
brew uninstall ios-webkit-debug-proxy
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice

brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
brew install --HEAD ios-webkit-debug-proxy
```

At the OSX level my console looks like this:

```
Device.installApp executing command: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vcremote/node_modules/ios-deploy/build/Release/ios-deploy --id 355c4a7afbd0e98ac9596c146fa1d051e9b2b3fe --nostart --bundle "/Volumes/DATA/r/F/ITOOLS/Tralala/Tralala/ARM64/Debug//Tralala.app" --timeout 5
Installed app on device: 'iPad'
GET /projects/2df69712-b4b8-43f3-9ada-fc50ca3fa6b1/build/ce4ed9aa-f673-4c78-99cb-968e2dc5bb7c/install?ver=1.4.0&appName=Tralala.app 200 5856ms
Debug Listener already listening
GET /debug/appRemotePath?package=com.Tralala&deviceUdid=xxxx 404 38ms - 196b
```

In Visual Studio, I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to start debugging. Unexecpted failure trying to reach vcremote: NotFound
```

First, the package name is invalid. But even If I changed it to com.Tralala, the same problem, 404.

Why? Do I miss something?

Note that the app won't debug in the Simulator either, it runs there but VS hangs to a message "Wait for application to launch. Please (re)launch ..."

I checked instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341623/could-not-connect-to-lockdownd-while-attempting-to-run-flutter-app) as well, no luck. It seems it can't find the app installed, but the app is there and `libimobiledevice` can see it.

Comment: Please also take a look [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/379419/cannot-debug-ios-c-app-on-physical-iphone.html) specially this section **Other notes on deploying and debugging from VS**

Comment: @Nouman where is that trust permission setting? *"The test device provides “trust” permission on the app that was deployed so that the app will execute. This can be set from Settings > General > Device Management. Select your Developer App account, and apply “trust” on the deployed app."*  Can't find this in iOS 12, besides, my app will execute when I tap it from the device.

Comment: [Settings > General > Device Management](https://support.meetcircle.com/hc/article_attachments/115003879972/MDMEnabled.jpg)

Comment: @Nouman there is nothing below my VPN setting.

Comment: Was it not there since the beginning or did it disappear recently, perhaps the device is not provisioned correctly. [please check this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/)

Comment: @Nouman This is not a xamarin app, it can run directly from Xcode... is that the issue? Only Xamarin apps are supported?

Comment: I assume you can only debug iOS apps with Visual studio if they are built on Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Forms or [Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/visual-cpp-for-cross-platform-mobile-development?view=vs-2019)

Comment: You have an option to [import an XCode project to Visual C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/import-an-xcode-project?view=vs-2019) to make it work from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Nouman yes I 've done that, the import works. From VS I can build the project. But running fails with a 404. The app is correctly installed , I can run it after building manually.